# Instead of xml files, can i define the layout from assets, by the web. android

Tags: android

Instead of xml files, can i define the layout from assets, by the web.
How can i define layout file without using xml files in android.
res/layout.
to
assets/www

Comment: Why don't you use a webview to load a web page instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your layout programatically (see [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-layout--mobile-3671%22here%22)) for details. So all you need to do then is define your layouts in any markup you like, download them at runtime, and parse them.

for example you might choose to use csv for simple layouts, which contains something like this:

```
 Button,wrap_content,wrap_content,Hello World
 TextView,wrap_content,wrap_content,Hello World Again
```

Then create your layout with something like this:

```
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    this.setContentView(rootLayout);

    String data=getDataFromFile();
    String[] controls = data.split("\n");

    for (String c:controls)
    {
        String[] d = c.split(",");

        if(d[0].equals("Button"))
        {
            int width;
            int height;
            if (d[1].equals("wrap_content"))
            {
                width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            }
            else if (d[1].equals("match_parent"))
            {
                width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            }

            //repeat for height

            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
            b.setText(d[3]);

            rootLayout.addView(b);
        }
    }
```

But you're making life extremely hard for yourself. Ask yourself why you feel you need to do this, and is there a better way of achieving  what you want to achieve?